# Como Definir Variável PHP 7 para POST?

Tags: php, formulário, sql-insert

Estou tentando gravar informações de um formulario em um base, porém quando eu gero o seguinte codigo abaixo é apresentado um erro no arquivo dizendo que:

```
Notice: Undefined index: txtFirstName in C:\xampp\htdocs\begin\service.php on line 64
Notice: Undefined index: txtLastName in C:\xampp\htdocs\begin\service.php on line 65
Notice: Undefined index: ddlGender in C:\xampp\htdocs\begin\service.php on line 66
Notice: Undefined index: txtMinutes in C:\xampp\htdocs\begin\service.php on line 67
Notice: Undefined index: txtSeconds in C:\xampp\htdocs\begin\service.php on line 68
Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli_query in C:\xampp\htdocs\begin\service.php on line 74
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in C:\xampp\htdocs\begin\service.php:74 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\begin\service.php on line 74
```

O código que estou usando para definir as variáveis é este, o qual é correspondente as linhas de erro acima.

Eu não sou Expert em PHP e não achei nenhuma resposta ao meu respectivo problema no doc do PHP. Alguém poderia me ajudar por favor. Estou usando o PHP7

```
$fname = htmlspecialchars($_POST['txtFirstName']);
$lname = htmlspecialchars($_POST['txtLastName']);
$gender = htmlspecialchars($_POST['ddlGender']);
$minutes = htmlspecialchars($_POST['txtMinutes']);
$seconds = htmlspecialchars($_POST['txtSeconds']);
$time = $minutes . ':' . $seconds;
```

Meu insert esta assim:

```
$mysqli_query($conect, 'INSERT INTO runners(first_name, last_name, gender, finish_time) values("$fname", "$lname", "$gender", "$time")');
```

Comment: `undefined index` significa que o array `$_POST` não contém os índices que você está procurando. Você precisa checar se tem alguma coisa neste array. Você pode usar `isset` ou o operador *null coalesce* (`??`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro é necessário que você envie os dados pelo verbo http `POST` vou deixar um exemplo usando formulário HTML padrão.

> Exemplo formulário HTML

```
<form action="nome-do-seu-php.php" method="POST">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Primeiro nome" name="txtFirstName" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="Ultimo nome" name="txtLastName" />
  <select name="ddlGender">
     <option value="M">Masculino</option>
     <option value="F">Feminino</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit"> Enviar dados</button>
</form>
```

Repare que na tag `form` eu coloco o atributo `method` com o valor `POST` e que nos `input`/`select` informo o atributo `name` com o nome que você receberá no `$_POST`

**Nota:** Não coloquei os dois últimos campos do seu script no formulário, então você pode estar adicionando e fazendo os testes.

Caso possa acontecer de você não receber a informação e você queira tratar há duas maneiras.

A primeira delas é fazendo uso do `isset` e a segunda que é mais simples e fazendo uso do coalesce `??`.

> Exemplo:

```
<?php
  // Exemplo do isset
  $fname = htmlspecialchars(isset($_POST['txtFirstName']) ? $_POST['txtFirstName'] : 'Valor Padrão');
  // Exemplo do coalesce
  $lname = htmlspecialchars($_POST['txtLastName'] ?? 'Valor Padrão');
```

Comment: Hiago, obrigado mano, Deus abençõe vc ai pela ajuda.

Porém quando salva no bando o ´values´ são gravados no banco com os nomes das variáveis.